# Google's analytics javascript in Facebook app is not executing in IE

Tags: google-analytics, facebook

google analytics is not tracking visits from IE in a Facebook app.  I've been digging around the internet and cannot find a precedent for this issue.

I have narrowed it down to the javascript not executing in the browsers which results in GA not tracking the page visit.

all help / advice / pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is picky about things like dangling commas etc, which other browsers interpret happily.

To check that your JS meets a reasonable baseline, use http://www.jslint.com/ (with the "Assume a browser" option). Helps me to eliminate a common source of quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Add following header (for php) will resolve your porblem. This caused by IE privacy.
Google for P3P header for more infomation. ^^

```
header("P3P: policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"IE is often a NIGHTMARE\"");
```